# Subtract a value from specific column in each list's dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a large list with 12 elements (dataframes). Each dataframe has the same numer of rows and columns.
I would like to subtract value = 150 from each row of the column AMOUNT. This has to be done for all dataframes from the list.
Here is an example of the dataframe.

```
df1
NAME   TIME  AMOUNT
1       20     456
2       30     345
3       15     122
4       12     267
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and subtract 150 from the 'AMOUNT' column

```
lapply(lst1, transform, AMOUNT = AMOUNT -150)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyerse)
map(lst1, ~ 
           .x %>%
               mutate(AMOUNT = AMOUNT - 150))
```